# Qt: Why doesn't my button get the signal?

Tags: qt, signals-slots, emit

Why didn't the **button** object get the sigKK() signal when the button was clicked?

When a signal is emitted, can **all qt objects** receive this signal?

The code is as follows:

```
class PushButton :  public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void sigKK();
};
```

The PushButton class inherits from QPushButton, but doesn't connect signals and slots here. Is this right?

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT    
public:
    explicit MainWindow(){
        resize(400,200);    
        connect(this,SIGNAL(sigKK()),this,SLOT(showRecv1()));   

        button = new PushButton();
        button->setText("Hello,All");
        button->resize(40,15);
        connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(buttonCK()));
        connect(button, SIGNAL(sigKK()),this,SLOT(showRecv2()));
            //**I can connect sigKK signal with showRecv2 slot here ?**** 
        button->show();
    }
    ~MainWindow(){      
    }
signals:
    void sigKK();
public slots:
    void showRecv1(){
        cout<<"recved 1"<<endl;
        resize(100,100);
    }
    void showRecv2(){
        cout<<"recved 2"<<endl;
        button->setText(".....");
    }
    void buttonCK(){
        emit sigKK();
        cout<<"emited"<<endl;
    }
private:
    PushButton *button ; 
};
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a signal is emitted, can all qt objects receive this signal ?

**No**. When a signal is emitted it is received only by QObjects with signals or slots connected to it.

Your MainWindow and your PushButton both have a signal with the same name... but they are still different signals. They are completely unrelated to each other. When MainWindow emits `sigKK`, that has no effect on PushButton's `sigKK`.

In your example, `sigKK` seems to be entirely unneccessary. Perhaps you could instead connect `clicked()` directly to the actions you want to perform?

```
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(showRecv1()));
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(showRecv2()));
```

Comment: but， my purpose is : when button is clicked, a sigKK() signal will be emited and the button will recvice it , how can i do this ?  I don't want to connect clicked() and showRecv2() on button.

Comment: Even if sigKK was emitted, your button has no slots to receive signals. What function on the button should be called when sigKK is emitted?

Comment: thanks Slavik81. i think i can use the code as follow: connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()),button,SIGNAL(sigKK()));  right ?

Comment: Yes. That will cause the signal `PushButton::sigKK()` to be emitted upon each click.